# Find all normal subgroups of $S_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, direct-product

I know that if $H_1,H_2$ are normal subgroups of $G_1,G_2$, respectively, then $H_1\times H_2$ is a normal subgroup of $G_1\times G_2$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is abelian, all its 4 subgroups are normal. The 3 normal subgroups of $S_3$ are $S_3$, $A_3$ and the trivial subgroup. Thus I can get 12 normal subgroups of $S_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_6$, but I do not know whether there are others, or how to find them.

Comment: There are other normal subgroups. Take for example a generator $g\in A_3$ and  $h\in\mathbb{Z}_6$ of order $3$. Then $\{(g^n,h^n)\}$ is a normal subgroup of $S_3\times\mathbb{Z}_6$ which is not a product of subgroups. I don't see a simple way to solve that, except for going manually through all subgroups one by one (which is not that difficult).

Comment: @freakish I don't know how to list all the subgroups...

Comment: @freakish, the subgroup you mention is not normal in S_3 x Z_6.

Comment: A few things that might help: If $N$ is normal in $S_3\times\mathbb{Z}_6$, then $N\cap (S_3\times\{e\})$ is normal in $S_3$; and the projection of $N$ onto the $S_3$ component is also normal in $S_3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the 12 normal subgroups mentioned in the initial post, there are two other normal subgroups:
$$
A_1=\{(e,\bar0),\,((12),\bar3),\,((13),\bar3),\,((23),\bar3),\,((123),\bar0),\,((132),\bar0)\};
$$
$$
A_2=\langle((123),\bar0),\,(e,\bar2),((12),\bar3)\rangle.
$$
The subgroup $A_1$ is of order 6, and the subgroup $A_2$ contains 18 elements.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected.